# flipping & rotating images on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to replicate this scrolling effect as seen here: http://prm.ooo.

In which the image elements flip and rotate continuously on a scroll as it enters and exits the page, I know this requires jquery/javascript and not just CSS alone.

So far I am able to rotate an image while scrolling.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Hi, @ninjasheeps. You need to post some of your programs and tell us what you've tried and ask specific questions. Here is a post that might help you get great answers on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code: http://prm.ooo/wp-content/themes/prmo/main.js  you can look at the source of any page and try and figure out how they did things. People also use plugins like [scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/) for this type of thing